# Interactive Bash-Course: How to catch user input and react on it

Tags: python, linux, bash, shell

I want to write a little 'game' for my girlfriend (and other people) so she can learn basic bash and linux commands with an interesting storyline.

Since I don't want her to be able to explore without me manually checking if she does it right , I need a way to catch her interactions with the commandline and the output.

Right now I see two approaches none of which I know if it works:

1. Use a python script **as the interpreter/login-shell,** pass commands on to os.system or subprocess and implement the 'game-logic' in that script. Problems with that: I can't teach her stuff like the ctrl-z,ctrl-d etc.
2. Use the actual bash as interpreter/login shell and make my script for the **'game-logic' run prior/after every command (as a kind of hook)**. Is that possible without digging in the bash-code itself?

Comment: The former is the way you'd have to do it (at least without a LOT of work. It is possible to limit the commands a user has access to). The downside is you'll lose autocomplete if you do it the naive way. You'll have to do clever things with ``readline`` to make it actually feel like a bash shell.

Comment: `run my script after every command` -> search for `PROMPT_COMMAND`.

Answer (score 1):

First off:

```
import signal, time
def signal_handler(signal, frame):
        print('You pressed Ctrl+<KEY>, ignoring!')
signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal_handler)
signal.signal(signal.SIGTSTP, signal_handler)
while 1:
    time.sleep(1)
```

There's a start on one of your problems.
Secondly, I don't see how you want to "catch" her interactions.. But i'd assume you'd have to be present anyway so why not just let her have two terminals and let her have a go at it while the "game" is running in a separate console where you simply input y/n depending if she did the correct task?

Or if you really wanna get geeky, why not set up a virtual environment where she can't do any harm and let her do whatever and reset it upon failure.. Give her 5 sets of instructions to do and see if she can google it? She needs to learn how to fetch information rather than learning "if i do what he says, i get cookie".

There's better "game" scenarios to implement a learning curve then having you jump in and correct everything, give her keywords to search for and teach her to just try **everything** she sees on the google results.. It can't go wrong, after all.. It's just a computer..

### A practical example:

1. Create a virtual machine with [qemu](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/QEMU) (guide is longer than it should, you only need a fraction to get started)
2. Install a base linux system on it
3. Take a snapshot
4. Create a script that reverts to the last snapshot and boots the OS
5. Give her (or him) a set of instructions such as "1: Install Python2.7, (keywords: archlinux python)"

I did this for a couple of network labs, people could mess up all they wanted.. Didn't matter because the next time they rebooted (via the script) the machine was as good as new. Only thing you have to do, is invoke a new snapshot when she (or he) is in a good place in your tutorial.